# how to make a function work in python

Tags: python, function

I wrote the following code in python and it works fine until I try to make it a function, can anyone help?

```
import random
def club():
    members=int(input("members"))
print (random.randint(1, members))
```

Comment: You certainly could find a better title

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 4 spaces ( or tab) per indentation level. And call the function of course.

```
import random
def club():
    members=int(input("members"))
    print (random.randint(1, members))

club()
```

Answer (score 0):

`members` is local to the `club` function, thus not visible to your `print` call

Answer (score 0):

`members` is considered to be a local variable within the `club` function. If you want to use it, you can return it. You can do something like this:

```
import random
def club():
    members = int(input("Members: "))
    return members
print(random.randint(1, club()))
```

Also, since Python is an Object-Oriented Language, you can set the value that `club` returns to a variable (or anything for that matter):

```
a = club() # Then a might be 5
b = random.randint(1, a)
```

And then use that variable elsewhere:

```
print(b)
```